# How to add swiping functionality on ListView?

Tags: flutter

How to add swiping functionality on ListView? I do not know the exact number of childs to use PageView, moreover I think having just a horizontal swipe on a scrollable widget is what will fit better.

Comment: what do you want to do after left / right swipe? anyway check how `Dismissible` widget is implemented

Comment: @pskink I will make network request to fetch some data and then render next page with ListViewBuilder which will use the data or maybe it will be some other widget based on recieved data...

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/400608f101/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/dismissible.dart#L591 - this is how `Dismissible` is implemented, i think you should follow that way and call your action on `onHorizontalDragEnd`

Answer (score 0):

if your want to add swipping functionality in PageView then you can use PageView.builder instead of just PageView.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).